# Add Dynamic AX SSRS reports to TFS source control

Tags: tfs, version-control, axapta, ssrs-2012

I googled a lot, bought some AX report development books and sifted through AX forms but to no avail: nobody seems to try to develop AX 2012 reports in a source controlled SSRS 2012 environment. 
I want to use Team Foundation Server to add source control to my reports. The problems I run into are:

1. Every time I open a report from the AOT a new report model project
   is created
2. The actual rdlc file that contains the report definitions is not located in    the project folder of this project but in some temporary folder in my User\AppData folder
3. When I leave a solution open and then load a new report model from the AOT it is added in the same project as is opened instead of a separate project.

Thanks for your help on how I should set up TFS source control for AX report development.

Comment: Do you mean you want to develop AX 2012 reports with SSRS 2012, and SSRS is version-controlled by TFS? Have you checked in your whole solution? When you want to open application, the application will be checked out. All operations to the application are on local machine. TFS won't invoke during this process. So not quite understand the relationship between your problems and TFS. Maybe you can provide more information.

Comment: YesI develop AX2012 reports with SSRS2012 version controlled by TFS and I checked in my whole solution. I don't have these problems when developping just SSRS-reports outside of AX. But if I work with AX and its AOT every report I open becomes one project in my solution and the rdlc file does not get source control.